# How do I connect and inserting records into pervasive sql in php

Tags: php, pervasive

I am working on a PHP project that needs to send data to Pastel.

How to connect to pastel's pervasive and insert the records directly for the pastel to use?

Comment: What version of Pervasive?   What OS is the PHP running on?  Do you have DDFs for the Pastel data files?

Comment: I am using v10 on Windows. Yes I can see Field.ddf, file.ddf, index.ddf, procc.ddf, attrib.ddf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP on Windows is relatively easy.  You'll need to create an ODBC DSN pointing to your database.  Then, you can use ODBC to connect. Here's a very simple sample using the PSQL demodata:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Mirtheil Software">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect("demodata","","");
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,"select * from Class");
echo "<table border=1>\n";
$numfields = odbc_num_fields($rs);
for($i=1;$i<=$numfields;$i++){
    $fn=odbc_field_name($rs,$i);
    echo "<th>$fn</th>";
}
echo "\n";
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
    echo "<tr>\n";
    for($i=1;$i<=$numfields;$i++){
    $fv=odbc_result($rs,$i);
    echo "<td>$fv</td>"; 
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
echo "<p>Number of Fields: $numfields</p>\n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting this error: 

Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application, SQL state IM014 in SQLConnect in C:\Apache24\htdocs\POS\conn\pervasive_conn.php on line 2
Could not connect

I guess because I'm running 64 bits and I cant get Pervasive driver for 64 bits

Comment: That's right.  There isn't a 64 bit ODBC driver for PSQL v10.  You'd have to upgrade to PSQL v11 or later (current version, as of December 2017 is v13).

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can go for PDO